# SSL certificate is not working in android mobile,iphone and Ipad

Tags: mobile, ssl, ssl-certificate

i did a intranet application and we added a SSL certificate for that application.That certificate is working in Desktop environment but its not working in mobiles.

May i Know whats the problem in certificate?

Comment: What's the URL to the server? Or do you think its a good idea to allow the world to bang on your server, but hide the server from the folks on Stack Overflow while asking for help :o

Answer (score 2):

There exist three most common reasons:

1. the certificate is issued by the CA that is unknown on the mobile device for any reason (eg. the root certificate of the chain is not listed among the trusted ones on the device).
2. CA certificate does have one or several levels of CA certificates before the root. In this case you need to include all CA certificates in the chain (excluding the self-signed root) with your server certificate, and ensure that the server sends all of them.
3. the certificate you use is self-signed and it was previously installed to desktop certificate storage as trusted. Such certificate of course won't be accepted on the mobile device unless/until it's installed as trusted on that device.